# Powershell invoke-sqlcmd from query in a txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I have TSQL insert statements in a multiple text file in a folder. I need to run on sql server using foreach loop in powershell. it should go to each file in a folder read the query execute that and terminate the connection again read the next file and do the same operation

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance KUMSUSHI7 -Query (Get-Content | For-each "C:\Drill\Task\SAMS Automation\Query.txt")
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 5):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` can take script file as a parameter, so no `-Query` is needed. There's [an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) on MSDN:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\TestSQLCmd.sql" | Out-File -filePath "C:\TestSQLCmd.rpt"
```

Thus, get a list of your sql files and pass the file names to `Invoke-Sqlcmd` like so,

```
gci "c:\some\path\*" -include *.sql | % {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $_.FullName
}
```